# Task Parallel library to query Active Directory (using DirectoryServices)

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, task-parallel-library, directoryservices

I'm pulling out about 400 objects out of Active Directory and then caching them for a period of an hour. The speed varies depending on traffic or which domain controller I hit but even at it's best it's still a little bit slow too slow for my liking.

I was wondering whether DirectoryServices is a reasonable candidate for the parallel library or if it's a bad idea for some reason. Has anyone had a

Has anyone had any experience of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can use a linq query to extract objects you only need to add .AsParallel()

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand parallel library will not change anything.

First of all, be sure that your DNS is correctly setup.

400 objects is not so much, you'll get best result optimizing you Directory request and minimizing network trafic (getting just the attributes you need).

You will get better performance using low level (native LDAP) protocol with [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols (S.DS.P).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx)